# Copy the struct to new one

Tags: c++, struct

I am trying to copy the members of struct to new one and making some adjustment to them. I am trying to print the value of the member but it is printing the address instead. I have commented on the parts.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
struct MyStruct
{
    char *name;
    int * countSize;
};
MyStruct * stCpy(MyStruct *oldStru) //pass the address of the struct and it copies its content
{
    MyStruct * newStru = new MyStruct; //allocating the memory
    newStru -> name = oldStru -> name; //copying the name
    newStru -> countSize = oldStru -> countSize -1; //setting the size to the size of arg struct -1;
    return newStru;

}
int main()
{
    int size = 10;
    char name = 'R';
    MyStruct myStrt{&name, &size};
    MyStruct * Strtptr = stCpy(&myStrt);
    cout <<"printing the name of newstruct" << Strtptr -> name <<endl; //prints the name fine.
    cout <<"printing the size of newStruct" << Strtptr -> countSize; // why is this printing the address instead?
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is nothing here that requires heap allocation. It looks like `stCpy` should really be a copy constructor. `MyStruct::name` should be a `std::string` and I have no idea what `MyStruct::countSize` is supposed to represent, but a pointer-to-int is almost certainly wrong. Put simply, there is no reason for this program to use _any_ pointers.

Comment: Have you considered not using any pointers, so you can use the default copy constructor? Right now, you have way bigger problems than just printing an address.

Comment: Read a [good C++ programming book](https://stroustrup.com/programming.html) then see [this C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp). If you compile with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) enable all warnings and debug info, so use `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` then use the [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) debugger

Comment: "_I am trying to copy the members of struct to new one and making some adjustment to them_" - If you find yourself in this position and you are not the person who designed it - look for good documentation.

Comment: Every time you make a copy, the recorded length gets shorter by 1 for some weird reason because you have this line `count = old -> count - 1;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cout <<"printing the size of newStruct" << Strtptr -> countSize; // why is this printing the address instead?
```

Because you're printing the pointer value of `Strptr->countSize`. What you want to print is the value which `coutSize` is pointing.

```
cout <<"printing the size of newStruct" << (*Strtptr -> countSize);
```

Comment: This helps, but the `int*` is still pointing at garbage. This doesn't fix the UB.

Comment: @cigien, You're correct, there's a problem with `stCopy()`. I could only answer why it was printing the address of `countSize` instead of the value.

Comment: Not true; `countSize` _is_ an address. At no stage is anyone printing the address _of_ `countSize`.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings, You're right, the code is not printing address of `countSize`. I made some changes on my answer. Thank you.

Comment: That's better :)

Answer (score 2):

First as `@cdhowie` suggested no need for heap allocation and `int*` and `char*`, you need to think c++ way;

to simplify your program:

```
struct MyStruct
{
    std::string name;
    int countSize;

    /* copy constructor */

    MyStruct(): name(""), countSize( 0 ) {}
    MyStruct( const std::string& n, const int& s ): name( n ), countSize( s ) {}
    MyStruct( const MyStruct& other )
    {
        name = other.name;
        countSize = other.countSize;
    }
    
};


int main()
{
    int size = 10;
    std::string name = "stackoverflow";

    MyStruct m1( name, size );

    MyStruct m2( m1 );

    std::cout <<"printing the name of newstruct " << m1.name << std::endl; 
    std::cout <<"printing the size of newStruct " << m1.countSize << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

to answer your question, using pointers evil anyway;

in below line, your not reducing value it's pointed to, rather your asking to point different address, which can lead to `UB`;

```
newStru->countSize = oldStru->countSize -1; //setting the size to the size of arg struct -1;
```

if you `cout` the address; you will see the difference, by doing your way, now `newStru->countSize` not pointing to the address of `oldStru->countSize`;

```
std::cout << "oldStru: " << oldStru -> countSize << std::endl; //0x7ffdd14e7464
std::cout << "newStru: " << newStru->countSize << std::endl; //0x7ffdd14e7460
```

you need `newStru->countSize` point to same address of `oldStru->countSize`;